# jQuery - show list items that match data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function for finding the active menu option and showing the `li` with the matching `data-type` only works if the `active` class is on the first or second `li`. If I put the active class on the third or fourth `li`, no items show for either table.

How do I show all of the items with the `data-type` that matches the `data-related` value with the `active` class?

Note the click function works fine, the issue is showing the `li` for the active selection on load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Retreive active list on load:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  $("[data-section='table']").each(function() {
    var $container = $(this);
    var item = $container.find(".billing__item");
    var active = $container.find(".ladder__ul li.active");
    var $id = item.attr("data-type");
    var datarel = active.attr("data-related");

    item.hide();
    // Find out what Li has the active class, then return matching items on load:
    if (datarel == "all") {
      item.css("display", "flex");
    }
    if (datarel == $id) {
      $(".billing__item[data-type='" + $id + "']").css("display", "flex");
    }
  });
  //Retreive active list on Click:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  $(".ladder__ul li").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $li = $(this);
    var $table = $li.closest("[data-section='table']");
    var $id = $li.attr("data-related");

    $(".ladder__ul li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $table.find(".billing__item").each(function() {
      var $item = $(this);
      var $type = $item.attr("data-type");
      //Hide every list on load::
      $item.hide();
      if ($li.attr("data-related") == "all") {
        $item.css("display", "flex");
      }
      if ($li.attr("data-related") == $type) {
        $item.css("display", "flex");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: .9rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer
}

.active {
  background: blue
}

[data-section='table'] {
  border: 2px solid;
  pading: 1.3rem
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-section="table">
  <ul class="ladder__ul">
    <li data-related="all">All</li>
    <li data-related="one" class="active">One</li>
    <li data-related="two">two</li>
    <li data-related="three">three</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="billing__list">
    <div class="billing__item" data-type="one">One</div>
    <div class="billing__item" data-type="two">Two</div>
    <div class="billing__item" data-type="one">One</div>
    <div class="billing__item" data-type="three">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-section="table">
  <ul class="ladder__ul">
    <li data-related="all">All</li>
    <li data-related="a">a</li>
    <li data-related="b" class="active">b</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="billing__list">
    <div class="billing__item" data-type="a">a</div>
    <div class="billing__item" data-type="b">b</div>
    <div class="billing__item" data-type="a">a</div>
    <div class="billing__item" data-type="b">b</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to nest your `data-section="table"` elements?

Comment: No, thank you for that. I have updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because `$id` is not equal to `datarel` 
`The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set.` 
ref: https://api.jquery.com/attr/ 
So your $id variable is always `one` because that's how you layout your elements in the html and One is the value of the first element with attribute `data-type`

```
<div class="billing__item" data-type="one">One</div>
<div class="billing__item" data-type="two">Two</div>
<div class="billing__item" data-type="one">One</div>
<div class="billing__item" data-type="three">Three</div>
```

I believe you are complicating things with the $id, you don't need it

```
$("[data-section='table']").each(function () {
    var $container = $(this);
    var item = $container.find(".billing__item");
    var active = $container.find(".ladder__ul li.active");
    var datarel = active.attr("data-related");
    item.hide();
    // Find out what Li has the active class, then return matching items on load:
    if (datarel == "all") {
        item.css("display", "flex");
    }
    $(".billing__item[data-type='" + datarel + "']").css("display", "flex");
});
```

Using `datarel` directly should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem from id. Because you get `$id` from `item.attr("data-type")` but the item is multiple element so it alway to get the first item data. That why at first section it work, but the second section work incorrect.

So you need to change your code like this:

```
//Retreive active list on load:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
$("[data-section='table']").each(function() {
  var $container = $(this);
  var item = $container.find(".billing__item");
  var active = $container.find(".ladder__ul li.active");

  var datarel = active.attr("data-related");

  item.hide();
  // Find out what Li has the active class, then return matching items on load:
  if (datarel == "all") {
    item.css("display", "flex");
  } else {
    $(".billing__item[data-type='" + datarel + "']", $container).css("display", "flex");
  }
});
```